# Does abpframework now have a domain service implementation similar to the previous IUserNavigationManager to get the user navigation menu?

Tags: abp

Does abpframework now have a domain service implementation similar to the previous `IUserNavigationManager` to get the user navigation menu?

The following is the version and environment used：

```
ABP-Version 2.8.0
User-Interface-Type: Angular
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Domain layer doesn't have info about presentation (web) layer.